Options for automated Q-Chem input file generation
I have a big number of .xyz files which I plan to run using Q-Chem, and I was wondering if there were any options for automatically generating Q-Chem input files from these .xyz files. I know that IQmol can generate an input file from an .xyz, but from what I know this can only be done one at a time. I was looking at packages like PyQchem, but this seems to require manually entering the coordinates, charge, and multiplicity.
Is there any sort of software or package which can automatically generate such input files from .xyz files?
Thanks!

Does this answer work for you? This would read a gaussian log file and generate new gaussian input files. You should be able to modify the script to do what you need. If you can provide a template .xyz file and Q-Chem input file, I can post the answer with the new script.

You don't need to write a script to generate a bunch of Q-chem input files. Alternatively, Q-chem has an option READ to read external .xyz file in the $molecule code deck:
$molecule
   READ filename
$end

Ref: https://manual.q-chem.com/4.3/sect-molinput.html

But this will read only one file, so, at the end, you need a script to run over the whole set of XYZ files.

@Camps Hi, sorry for the unclear explanation. I meant that the OP does not need to write a script to generate input files, but rather one script that loops over input files and submits calculation jobs all at once.
